# EF pagination technique to fetch few selected data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i rare use EF. so i want to know how could we page data.just got a code

```
List<customers> _customers = (from a in db.customers select a).ToList();
var _dataToWebPage = _customers.Take(50);
```

see the above two line and it seems it fetch all data from db and in second line it take 50 data out of many.

does the above code hit db twice ?
or EF generate sql in such way as a result it will fetch only 50 records from db ?

when EF understand that it need to hit db to get data? please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does:

- It loads all selected data into client memory on `ToList()`. Everything that comes after `ToList` happens in client memory, not server side
- It constructs a deferred enumerable from `Take(50)` on the client list. It will evaluate when you actually iterate the `_dataToWebPage` enumerable

How to implement paging:

Make sure to order the selected data, otherwise some SQL providers ignore `Skip` or provide other unexpected results. Then apply `Skip(...).Take(...)` on the `IQueryable<T>`, before loading the data into client memory.

Example code for paging:

```
int countPerPage = 50;
int currentPage = 1; // zero based index
List<customers> page_customers = db.customers
    // you need to decide how to order your data
    .OrderBy(a => a.Id)
    .Skip(currentPage * countPerPage)
    .Take(countPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: why we need to use order by when doing paging by EF but when we fetch data from db without order by clause with pagination using rownumber function then get no data

Comment: @Tridip you should have a look at the generated SQL for the queries with / without ordering (directly in debugger view or by activating logging on the dbcontext). EF is not doing any magic - it's mostly converting between the SQL results and your class structure.

Answer (score 1):

The linq query returns an [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to craft your queries. Here the sql that will be generated will take only the 50 elements, not the whole collection. When you call `ToList()` on your `IQueryable` the query hits the database and you receive the results.

This is how you want to do it:

```
var _dataToWebPage = (from a in db.customers select a)
    .OrderBy(a => a.Id) // It is an unordered collection, so you have to order it
    .Take(50)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Never try paging without ordering on an unordered dataset.

Comment: I think EF will throw an exception if you attempt a `Take` or `Skip` on an unordered set

Comment: Note taken. I fixed the answer

Comment: so my code fetch all data from db and  store all in memory and then take 50. if yes then let me know what my above code is doing?

Comment: @grek40 are you try to say if we do the paging by EF without orderBy then i will get exception? if yes but when we fetch data from db without order by clause with pagination using rownumber function then get no data.

Comment: @Tridip I'm not saying that you would definitely get an exception or empty data... just that the result would be unreliable, so better get ordered results for paging. I don't know whether all entity framework db providers would behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code EF hits database once, but there is problem that it takes all the records from database and then cutting first 50 records. EF hits database when you are calling `ToList()` method. You need to call `Take(50)` first and then `ToList()` to get only 50 records from database.

Comment: so my code fetch all data from db and  store all in memory and then take 50. if yes then let me know what my above code is doing?